# Is threading is necessary to use in SQLite based Delphi app?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, delphi

I am very much beginner in Delphi development. I want to make desktop application that include Sqlite database and browser. The application  is mostly based on CRUD operations but when ever user update data into database the change will be displayed on browser on another panel of the application. it also generates printable pdf. The pdf is generated by C# code[NReco Library]. Is I have to use Multi Threading in to my application to make my ui responsive in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQlite3 has very low response time. A simple SELECT is less than a few microseconds in practice, since it is an embedded database, and no network layer is involved.

No need to implement background threading with SQLite3.

For demanding content, e.g. reading a lot of data, you could:

- Use proper paging (e.g. read 10K rows each time);
- Call `Application.ProcessMessage` every now and then;
- Add a timeout in the loop.

You should design your app just as if it was a client app. Too much data is killing the data, both for the UI and the User. Only get what you need to for proper display.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably  not necessary, but it is always a good idea to run long running tasks on a separate thread. Delphi makes that really easy so it should be of no concern.

Alternatively, you can use techniques like periodically calling Application.ProcessMessages() to keep your UI responsive.

Comment: I like your first sentence, but not your second. `Application.ProcessMessages` is an antipattern IMHO.

Comment: I disagree... there are great many cases where Application.ProcessMessages() is exactly what you need and works great (e.g. processing 1000 items in a loop, 50-100ms each). other cases, like calling db or some external longer running process - not so much

Comment: In most cases if you are using Application.ProcessMessages, then you should look at leveraging threads instead.